# Arduino distance between two lines

Tags: c++, time, arduino

I am trying to figure out how to get the Arduino to find out the time distance between two lines.

At the minute the Arduino knows when it is on a line, what I want to to make it do is count the time between going off line 1 and passing line 2.

```
void loop()
{
    while(onLine)
    {
    //on the line
       if (alreadyPassedLine)
       {
        //2nd time robot hit line
        totalTimeTaken = timeCounter;
       }
       if (!alreadyPassedLine)
       {
        //1st line
        startCounting = true;
       }
    }
   while(!onLine)
   {
      if(startCounting)
      {
        timeCounter++;
      }
   }
}
```

*The code above is my thought process to the solution, and I have tried implemented this without any success*

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you want to use [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono):

```
void loop()
{
    std::time_t start_time;
    std::time_t end_time;
    while(onLine)
    {
        //on the line
        if (alreadyPassedLine)
        {
            //2nd time robot hit line
            end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        }
        if (!alreadyPassedLine)
        {
            //1st line
            start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        }
    }
    std::time_t total_time = end_time - start_time;
}
```